# How to fetch an output in python using linux which keeps on generating every 30 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I want to capture an output in python.

My code:-

```
import os

import sys 

import subprocess

import time

cmd = './abc'

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

time.sleep(12)

stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 

sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")

sys.stdout.close()

sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin

proc.terminate()
```

Problem is it never comes out of ./abc and is always stuck there. I need kill the process .
Normally i have to give CTRL+C to come out of it.
In this case how can i capture the output and save in a file which comes every 30 seconds .I need to capture it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of a subprocess when starting it. Consider the following:

```
with open('proc.out', 'w') as proc_out:                                             
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=proc_out)
```

The call to `run` is blocking, but all the output is written to the output file. Once your subprocess finished, so does your Python script. You can still kill it prematurely, however.

Comment: I want it to close the connection after 30 seconds , is that possible...since i need to kill it.

Comment: You can add the `timeout` parameter to the `run()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer and since Using only timeout would throw error
what i did was i added it to try and expect block.

import os

import sys

import subprocess

import time

cmd = './abc'

try:

```
with open('proc.out', 'w') as proc_out:
    
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=proc_out , timeout = 30)
```

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:

```
pass
```